# How to get median is SAS?

Tags: sas

How to get median is SAS?

I wrote a script but it doesn't pront me the median

here is my script:

```
   FILENAME book1 URL "http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~liadshek/Books.txt";
   DATA book;   
   INFILE book1 firstobs=2;
   INPUT year numberBooks words copies annual author$;
   RUN;

   PROC MEANS median;
   VAR year numberBooks words copies annual;
   OUTPUT out = MeanForData;
   RUN;
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine for me in Base SAS.

You just need to open the output window to see the results (they are sent there via the Output Delivery System).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The MEDIAN needs to be on the output.

```
   FILENAME book1 URL "http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~liadshek/Books.txt";
   DATA book;   
   INFILE book1 firstobs=2;
   INPUT year numberBooks words copies annual author$;
   RUN;

   PROC MEANS;
   VAR year numberBooks words copies annual;
   OUTPUT out = MeanForData median= /autoname;
   RUN;
```